# ag-grid - href download tag being ignored

Tags: html, ag-grid

Not sure if there is something I am doing wrong, or does AG Grid break some HTML5 attributes?

I am using a cellRenderer in two columns and one I am using a standard

```
<a href="file.png" >imgsrc</a>
```

while the other one I am using a

```
<a href="file.png" download>imgsrc</a>
```

I even tried the newest option

```
<a download="file.png">imgsrc</a>
```

and all of them act exactly the same, using the default behavior of just opening the file.  I have looked at the rendered page and they are rendering as intended, just not being honored for some reason.

Is this a known issue, or is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

I found what my issue was, and it didn't have anything to do with the AG Grid, but the way I was implementing the href tag.  I was using a full URL to the download file instead of using a relative one.  This was the way my JSON file was coming in, with the full URL instead of relative.  I changed it to a relative path for all the file links and the behavior is now as expected.